# WinForms application needs to close unhandled exception

Tags: c#, winforms, unhandled-exception

I have a windows forms application. It is implemented like a tray icon so when a message arrives it pops up above all other windows.
Somehow I have an unhandled exception on a few systems:

> Mnclient has encountered a problem and needs to close. We are sorry for
>   the inconvenience.

Report contains next:

> EventType : clr20r3     P1 : mnclient.exe     P2 : 1.0.0.0     P3 :
>   51dec1c0 P4 : system     P5 : 4.0.0.0     P6 : 50485745     P7 : 57f
>   P8 : 0      P9 : system.io.filenotfoundexception\

I can't catch this error in my code. What could be the reason?

**BTW** If I don't close this error-report window, my app continues to work as everything is fine.

So I'm thinking that some system component is trying to close it. But is it possible? And why?

Any other ideas?

Comment: is your program try to connect to the Internet?

Comment: Finally unhandled exception handled. The problem was in external library, that my app uses. The error happened inside this lib, it didn't appear on my app, but raised an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a handler for `UnhandledException` in your program so that it can help you debug the issue further and handle the exception from wherever it's been thrown (as well as other unhandled exceptions). For example

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (s,e) => 
               {
                  Exception ex = (Exception)e.ExceptionObject;
                  Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);                                          
               };
```